# Logout from dotnetcore app authenticated by onelogin using oauth

Tags: onelogin

[I am using below app to connect onelogin through my .Netcore2.2 web app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBDe0.jpg)Onelogin logout from .NetCore 2.2 mvc webapp.

I am using onelogin to authenticate users and logged into the system in dotnetcore2.2. for onelogin i have used OAuth for authentication. user can log in successfully but not able to logout from app as there is no proper documentation provided by onelogin.

what i did is revoke that token successfully then use HttpContext.SignoutAsync() to logout from webapp. but its not working.

Anybody have solution on above problem.

Thanks in advance.

```
var options = new OAuthOptions
        {
            AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://demo.onelogin.com/oidc/auth",
            UserInformationEndpoint = "https://demo.onelogin.com/oidc/me",
            TokenEndpoint = "https://demo.onelogin.com/oidc/token",
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/callback"),
            ClaimsIssuer = "https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc",
            ClientId = "2fljk230-9456-0975-5hgd-02649b659666158745",
            ClientSecret = "7856f543awer33948968b0fgh5b82d4c21a1e29fec87365c32341ba72e20g89",
            SaveTokens = true,
```

above is for Onelogin OAuth configuration

```
var client = new HttpClient();
        var formData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", accessToken),
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token_type_hint", "access_token"),
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "2fljk230-9456-0975-5hgd-02649b659666158745"),
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "7856f543awer33948968b0fgh5b82d4c21a1e29fec87365c32341ba72e20g89")
      });

        var uri = String.Format("https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/token/revocation");

        var res = await client.PostAsync(uri, formData);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please edit your question to add more details, including the  code that is causing this issue?

Comment: my first step is to Revoke onleogin token and then signout from the onelogin. Is this Correct? Please help me to get rid from this situation. I can login successfully, get users using apis, but not able to LogOut.

I tried other providers like OKTA,PingOne they logged just by redirecting to their logout url by passing idtoken and postLogoutRedirectUri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to consider here. You have the tokens issued by Onelogin, but you also have a session with Onelogin which is what provides your user with SSO.

To be clear, there is no one clean way to log a user out of Onelogin using OIDC. So my recommendation is;

1. Kill all tokens locally. This will leave the tokens as valid in Onelogin for a period of time, but they only exist in Onelogin so the risk surface is minimal.
2. Kill the Onelogin session. You could try sending the user to https://login.ourtesco.com/logout but for belt and braces you'll need this API, which should only be available to you if you have a backend to the app to allow you to protected the clientid/secret appropriately.
   https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/log-user-out

Comment: Above code is correct, we have to revoke token first then need to call onelogin loguserout api.
The Mistake i did was i pass access token which has low grants. 
So we will have to generate API CLIENT credentials with Manage all type. then the token generated using this credentials will allow you to logout from app.